# Getting wrong results from a Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, file, dispatcher

I have a small `WPF` application that needs to enumerate through all files in a specified directory and check if a certain string exists in it. this is the search method:

```
private void btnSearch_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Thread t = new Thread(()=>search(@"c:\t", "url", true));
  t.Start();
}

private void search(string path, string textToSearch, bool ignoreCase)
{
  foreach (string currentFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
  {
    int lineNumber = 0;
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(currentFile))
    {
      lineNumber++;
      if (line.Contains(textToSearch))
      {
        lbFiles.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          //add the file name and the line number to a ListBox
          lbFiles.Items.Add(currentFile + "     " + lineNumber);
        }));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that if the specified string is found more than once in the file, the line number will be the latter for all occurrences. for a text file that has the following lines:

**abcd**
**EFG**
**url**
**hijk123**
**url**

the `listbox` will look like this:

[image: ListBoxResult]

when stepping through the code with a breakpoint I can see that immediately after steping out of the search method it "jumps" back into the `BeginInvoke` declaration.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: This is intended behavior! `BeginInvoke` creates an asynchronous operation and returns immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're closing over the variable `lineNumber`.  `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for the delegate to be called on the UI thread.  By the time it manages to get invoked `lineNumber` has been incremented a number of times.

There are two solutions.  Create a more localized copy of `lineNumber` to close over so that the changes aren't seen later:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(currentFile))
{
  lineNumber++;
  if (line.Contains(textToSearch))
  {
    var lineNumberCopy = lineNumber;
    lbFiles.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
      //add the file name and the line number to a ListBox
      lbFiles.Items.Add(currentFile + "     " + lineNumberCopy );
    }));
  }
}
```

Or use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`, so that `lineNumber` is read from before it has a chance to be incremented.